# ICEFaces Security

Tags: security, jsf, xss, icefaces

I have 2 security concerns that my client has come up with and I am stuck.

In order to avoid browsers caching sensitive information, the client's security guidlines require that POST requests do not return 200 response.  Initially I set up a phaseListener to deal with this but the only requests that came through were GETs.  I discovered that the POST request the client's security team were complaining about were ajax calls to the BlockingServlet.  How can I set up something similar for this?  I don't really understand how icefaces deals with the information stored on a form and how I can ensure that this info is not stored by the browser.  I have implemented the no-cache headers but that's not exactly solid security.

The phaseListener I used was basically http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html

The client is also concerned that input parameters are not properly validated providing a entry point for XSS. The example they gave was also going through the blockingServlet.  I suspect that ICEFaces has something built in to deal with this but I can't find any information about it.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[XSS is an output problem](https://sitewat.ch/en/Blog/5),  you can't cram all input data though some magic function and expect your application to be 100% safe from xss.  This will never work for any application,  because XSS just doesn't work that way.   Make sure you test your application for vulnerability like XSS and SQL Injection,  there are free solutions like [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About) and the open source [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/).

To prevent caching make sure this http header element is set:

`Cache-Control: no-store`

No other method should be used.

Comment: Thanks, I found a JIRA issue wrt to the XSS, [link](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-6657) and so it looks like there's not much I can do about it in my application.  We are currently fixed on our version of ICEFaces.  I believe this is as you say an output problem, the problem being that icefaces returns this unchecked code.  Still working on the GET/POST problem...

Comment: @user1058732 first and foremost you must always keep your libraries up to date,  if you don't you will get hacked for sure.  But besides the obvious,  ICEFaces is a js library,  this might be DOM based XSS.

Comment: Thanks Rook but you should remember that as a consultant you don't always have the option of using up-to-date libraries.  The company I'm working with has a system where no software including java libraries can be used until it has been approved, and that includes versions.  Also ICEFaces is more than just a js library, it's an AJAX bridge, a nice idea but when things like this come along it starts to fall down.  Since I posted this we've moved to RichFaces which isn't really a bridge in the same way, it's more just a js library on the front and ways to connect with it on the back.

Comment: @user1058732 sounds like you have much bigger security problems on your hands than just XSS.  Your whole development cycle is flawed.